# Trying to run GA in R, getting Error in if (any(x < 0)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I am relatively new to R and need to set up a genetic algorithm to find an equation that would produce a certain number of prime numbers.

```
install.packages("GA")
install.packages("matlab")
library(GA)
library(matlab)

f <- function(x)
{
  #initialize fitness score
  score <- 0 
  #set test values for k
  k <- seq(from = 1, to = 100,by = 1)
  #test if the result of the formula (k^2 + ak + b) is a prime number using test k values
  for (i in k) {
    if (isprime(i ^ 2 + x[1] * i + x[2]) == 2) {
    score = score + 1
    }
  }
  #return fitness score
  return(score)
}

lbound <- 2
ubound <- 1000

GA <- ga(type="real-valued",fitness=f,popSize = 10,pcrossover = 0.8,pmutation = 0.1, maxiter=30, run=20, lower = lbound, upper = ubound)
```

When I try to run the GA part, I get the following error:

```
> GA <- ga(type="real-valued",fitness=f,popSize = 10,pcrossover = 0.8,pmutation = 0.1, maxiter=30, run=20, lower = lbound, upper = ubound)

 Error in if (any(x < 0)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code happens because it tries to find x[2] when it doesn't exist.

If you read the Rastrigin example for GA function the vignette, for 2 values you need 1. specify a function with 2 inputs and 2. use a wrapper on this function

```
f <- function(x1,x2)
# two variables
{
  #initialize fitness score
  score <- 0 
  #set test values for k
  k <- seq(from = 1, to = 100,by = 1)
  #test if the result of the formula (k^2 + ak + b) is a prime number using test k values
  for (i in k) {
    if (isprime(i ^ 2 + x1 * i + x2) == 2) {
    score = score + 1
    }
  }
  #return fitness score
  return(score)
}

lbound <- 2
ubound <- 1000

GA <- ga(type="real-valued",
#the wrapper is here
fitness=function(x)f(round(x[1]),round(x[2])),
popSize = 10,
pcrossover = 0.8,pmutation = 0.1, maxiter=30, 
run=20, lower = rep(lbound,2), upper = rep(ubound,2))
```